# ShowWindow not working from a DLL on a 64-bit OS?

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, setwindowshookex, showwindow

I have a process that calls `SetWindowsHook` to catch keyboard events. In the DLL that processes the events, I conditionally call `ShowWindow` on the handle of the window of the process who set the hook.

That code works perfectly on a 32-bit OS (XP) and as a 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS, but when compiled to 64-bit, the window is not showing.

The code to make the window visible is:

```
if (idx == passlen) {
    HWND h = FindWindow(NULL,windowNameToShow);
    ShowWindow(h,SW_SHOW);
    idx = 0;
    logger->backerase(passlen - 1);
    nextCharToMatch = passPointer;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at below article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384203(v=vs.85).aspx